# Can I bind UI components to models with Amplify Studio without DataStore enabled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm exploring using AWS Amplify for a personal project. I'm finding many tutorials for data binding, using collections, building forms with the Amplify UI... all features that I am excited to use. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to use many of Amplify Studio's features without enabling Amplify DataStore, a feature that I do not need for my project (and would prefer the simplicity of an architecture without it).

I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere (in AWS docs, stackoverflow answers, google searches...) that says enabling DataStore is required to bind my models to my UI components using Amplify's `UI Library`.

The only message that comes close is `Enable DataStore to edit your data model visually` on the `Data` tab in Amplify Studio, suggesting that enabling DataStore is required to modify the `schema.graphql` file using the UI, which feels very arbitrary to me.

I can't understand why DataStore would be mandatory for so many of Amplify Studio's features, and since I can't find any documentation specifying this... I feel like I'm misunderstanding something. But Amplify Studio also seems to be hinting that DataStore is indeed required.

Can I leverage AWS Amplify Studio's `UI Library` feature to bind my UI components to my data models without enabling DataStore?

Answer (score 0):

Digging more through the AWS documentation, I came across this:

https://docs.amplify.aws/console/data/data-model/#data-modeling-in-amplify-studio

> All data models built with Studio work with Amplify DataStore out-of-the-box.

Another way to word that could be:

> Building a data model with Amplify Studio requires enabling Amplify DataStore for your project.

Looks like I have to accept enabling Amplify DataStore for my project in order to leverage the rest of Amplify Studio's features.

Answer (score 0):

DataStore is not required for modeling data, you can enable GraphQL in Studio or via the CLI. Then you can wire to your components in the UI Library. The only place where DataStore appears to be required is in the Form Builder, which is lame, and how I landed on this post.